# NodeJS and ExpressJS app memory keeps increasing as the load increases

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, memory-leaks

I have a NodeJS and ExpressJS app running with Nginx on it's front. The app is pretty big and we have around a millions users per day. Memory of the app keeps growing as the load increases. And, at a point requests starts getting dropped as there is no more memory left on the server.

My initial guess was some module / snippet is giving memory leaks in the code, explore memory heaps and profiled the app. but, still not found the culprit. Any suggestions??

Comment: It's probably line 39 of `app.js`. In all seriousness though, it's hard to give answers when you don't present relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spawn few more machines with higher RAM. Then use HAProxy and sticky sessions and balance the load accordingly.
Also you can use cluster mode and pm2 tools.